# Very new to Javascript and html and programming in general Y/N if problem

Tags: javascript, html

I made a very simple code to pop up two questions, ask about age and if you have drivers license. What i want it to do is to answer the following: over 21 and Y = you can drive; under 21 and Y = you can drive; under 21 and N = you can't drive; over 21 and N = you can't drive.

The problem here is in the case of under 21 and Y because it says you can't drive, I have tried with || and && and two ifs, and the problem is different but similiar in one case.

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">

<script>
    function skipLine() {
        document.write("<br>");
    }

    function print(phrase) {
        document.write(phrase);
        skipLine();
    }

    var age = parseInt(prompt("What's your age?"));
    var haveLicense = prompt("Do you have drivers licence Y or N");

    if((age >= 21) && (haveLicense == "Y")) {
            print("You can drive");
        }

    else {
        print("You can't drive");
    }

</script>
```

Comment: Seems like age doesn't matter at all. Someone can drive if and only if they have a license according to your truth table. Age being greater or less than 21 doesn't matter in any way. `canDrive(age, hasLicense) = hasLicense`

Answer (score 0):

```js
function skipLine() {
  document.write("<br>");
}

function print(phrase) {
  document.write(phrase);
  skipLine();
}

var age = parseInt(prompt("What's your age?"));
var haveLicense = prompt("Do you have drivers licence Y or N");

if (haveLicense == "N") {
  print("You can't drive");
} else {
  print("You can drive");
}
```